# Finite Inseparable Extension

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

Preparing for my Galois theory exam in may and i am faced with the following question.

Give an example of a finite inseparable extension with a sketched proof of its inseparability

I have the following proposition

**Proposition** Suppose $f ∈ F[X]$ is irreducible and inseparable over $F$. Then $char F = p,$ for
some prime number $p$, and there is a polynomial $g ∈ F[X]$ such that $f(X) = g(X^{p}).$

Which makes me think of the frobenius map

$\sigma : F \mapsto F$

$x \mapsto x^{p}  $

where $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$ prime (note this map is a homomorphism)

However i dont really know how to use any of this, or even if i am on the right lines for finding a finite inseparable extension.

Comment: You need to go to *infinite* fields of positive characteristic, as any finite field is perfect. Try $\;\Bbb F_p(x)/\Bbb F_p(x^p)\;$ , with $\;x\;$ a transcendental element over $\;\Bbb F_p\;$

Comment: So the question giving in this question is not possible as it asks for a finite extension?

Comment: $\mathbf F_p(x)/\mathbf F_p(x^p)$ is a finite extension.